# Is there any way to know how many close votes you've cast?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Is there any way to know how many close votes you've cast, including those which have aged away and on deleted questions? I know that there's the closure tab in the votes section in your profile, but that doesn't show deleted questions, so I can't get an accurate number from that.

Note that I don't need any particular questions but it'd just be interesting to see just how many questions I've voted to close.

Comment: Cast a ridiculously large number of votes, run for moderator, and Shog9 may look it up and tell you. (Worked for me, anyway.)

Comment: @Wooble: must mean I haven't cast too many then, I already tried your second suggestion :(

Answer (score 2):

The data from deleted posts is also missing from SEDE you only get a very rough idea of the numbers.

[See my answer on:  Get the Number of Closed Votes I Cast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55846/get-the-number-of-closed-votes-i-cast/234794#234794)

excerpt from that answer:

You could describe [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205056/where-did-i-succesfully-close-voted?sd=2014-01-01&ed=2014-04-01&UserId=578411#graph) as the *overview of the total number of posts that got closed on a certain day and the number of posts that were closed because I used my close vote on that post*.